# Does the structure of the module's src folder matter?

Tags: 8, debugging

I've read about the [Basic Structure](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/basic-structure) guide to building a Drupal 8 module. It's great that it outlines the basic files needed to get a module up and running.

Where it falls short is the contents of the `src` folder.

I've seen modules with the usual folders like `src/Access`, `src/Plugins`, `src/Form`. But I've also seen ones that appear to be arbitrarily named. Some files are referenced in annotations and yaml config, while some Drupal magically just knows about without some reference.

Does the folder structure matter? Does Drupal care if I put controllers in `src/MaybeNotControllers`? Are plugins like, formatters and widgets, still discoverable if not put in `src/Plugins`? Is there a definitive guide to what files go where and how Drupal finds out about them?

Comment: It's reeeeally hard to answer this exhaustively. The folder structure matters insofar as it needs to match namespaces for autoloading purposes. For the majority of real world usages the structure itself is arbitrary, but there are some conventions, and also exceptions. Plugins are one of the exceptions, as are entities and other annotated things. Controllers and forms tend to be conventionally located, but because they're most often referred to explicitly (e.g. explicitly setting the form or controller for a route), they don't _have_ to be.

Comment: Yes,  plugins (entities are also plugins) are the exception. @Joseph, you find more infos in the docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/annotations-based-plugins

Comment: For convention, there is not much need to name "Controllers" to something else - particularly if this code is contributed back out in some way.